# Imagination crashes

Tags: slideshow

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 as well as Budgie 20.04.  Imagination crashes when I import a slideshow file created by Imagination as well as when I attempt to save a newly created file.  I installed it using Software Center and then uninstalled it and reinstalled it with Synaptic.  This made no difference.  At the Imagination website there is no way to report a bug.  I do not see any alternatives for making a slide show video.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello, there is a way to report bugs https://sourceforge.net/p/imagination/_list/tickets

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I finally found the location and filed a report.  I am trying Kdenlive and having problems with it as well in Ubuntu 20.04.  It crashes when you add music.